# Custom post-type's pagination not working in category.php

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

I have this code to the file category.php :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
<div id="all">
<div id="todo">
<?php 
$my_query = null;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>array('post','articulo'), 'paged' => $paged, 'category_name'=>single_cat_title('', false), 'posts_per_page' => 10));
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); 
if ($my_query->post->post_type == 'post') {?>

<div id="post">
<div id="postimagen"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', $attr ); ?></a></div>
<div id="postcontent">
<div id="categorias">
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
echo '<li class="cat-' .$category->cat_name. '"><a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'">' . $category->cat_name . '</a></li>';}?>
</div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
<div id="info">
<div id="informacion">Escrito por <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> el <?php the_time('d/m/Y') ?> a las <?php the_time('G:i'); ?></div>
<div id="numcoment"><?php comments_number('0 Comentarios', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios' );?></div>
</div>
<?php the_excerpt() ?>
<div id="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Continuar</a></div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php } if ($my_query->post->post_type == 'articulo') {?>

<div id="post">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="postcontent2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
<div id="postmeta">
Escrito por <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> el <?php the_time('d/m/Y') ?> a las <?php the_time('G:i'); ?>
<div id="numcoment"><?php comments_number('0 Comentarios', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios' );?></div>
</div>
<?php the_content(false); ?>
<div id="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Continuar</a></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<?php } else; endwhile;?>
<div id="navigation">
<div class="previous"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Anterior' ) ); ?><div class="clear"></div></div>
<div class="next"><?php next_posts_link( __( 'Siguiente' ) ); ?><div class="clear"></div></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); get_footer(); ?>
```

But the pagination doesn't work in the categories where only there are custom post-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that pagination is based on the *main query*. Whether or not pages exist is determined by the query that is run before the template is loaded. When you create a new query in the template, it's not connected in any way to that default main query.

The proper way to alter the main query is via the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action:

```
function wpa_custom_post_types_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'articulo' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_custom_post_types_category' );
```

Comment: I see posts on both of those pages? you should get rid of your custom query and run the normal loop.

Comment: Not work: http://pastebin.com/fmC1ru3E

Comment: With the normal loop, still not working

Comment: `if (post_type == 'post')` is invalid. [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and fix your php errors.

Comment: see also [`get_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) function for determining post type within the loop.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant post_type - assumed 'post_type' in .../category.php on line 11

Notice: Use of undefined constant post_type - assumed 'post_type' in .../category.php on line 31

Comment: use `if( get_post_type() == 'post' )` and `if( get_post_type() == 'articulo' )` instead.

Comment: The normal loop with `if( get_post_type() == 'post' ) and if( get_post_type() == 'articulo' )` not work in search.php

Comment: it's probably best to post another question about what you're trying to accomplish, since this is a separate issue, and post your code.